# Is there a maven JBOSS dependency that includes all JBOSS runtime jars?

Tags: maven, jboss

I have a maven application that will be deployed to JBOSS 5.1 as a war. I want to know how to get it so that Maven can use the JBOSS 5.1 jars (i.e. all the jars in the common/lib folder and any other resources available to JBOSS at runtime) at compile time but not bundle them into the war file.

I thought I could just include some kind of JBOSS dependency with provided scope to do this however I can't find such a dependency. I have done a good bit of searching and can't really find such a dependency. There are a lot of references to pointing to a central JBOSS repository and pulling dependencies from there. I thought there would be just one global dependency that would include all JBOSS runtime jars. Os there such a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need more than the standard Java EE API like JBoss packages or resolve some compatibility problems, you can use this dependency :

**For JBoss / Java EE 7 Specification APIs**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**For JBoss / Java EE 6 Specification APIs**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**For JBoss WildFly 8.2.0.Final complete runtime dependencies**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-parent</artifactId>
    <version>8.2.0.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now, you can also use those POM files to extract the specific dependencies you need.

This could be useful in remote debug time to let your IDE resolve automatically the server dependencies jars and sources currently loaded, or appearing in stacktraces ... in development mode.

In a production MAVEN build, you probably just need this kind of configuration (depending on your JBoss version) :
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/wildfly-8/maven-configuration-for-java-ee-7-projects-on-wildfly

Answer (score 2):

Considering JBoss is an EE container, adding the JavaEE dependency should be enough.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Scope provided ensures that JBoss's own libraries are used once the application is deployed to the server.

Comment: this does not include other dependencies provided by JBoss such as Log4j, apache commons, hibernate, xml apis, schedulers, and of course all the jboss specific jars ...

Comment: Yes, this provides just the EE runtime part - everything else is quite trivial to add as you just use the same (Log4j, hibernate, ...) library in Maven with the scope provided tag.

Comment: This involve that you know exactly which versions of jars are provided in the JBoss version you run. By experience, I know that's not always as simple as you said, because it may not be explicitly written, or the libraries provided are modified by JBoss team. So, your answer is sufficient for covering many cases, but does not answer the real question : what are the JBoss runtime jars ?

Comment: You might get your answer if this gets implemented: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-430